# Program to Copy File Path with Mac OS X (that works with Open With)?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, path, clipboard

I'm looking for a free application that I can use to copy paths in Mac OS X. The paths are listed in a third party program ([Fresh](http://www.ironicsoftware.com/fresh/index.HTML)) and I can right click them. I wish they would just build in an option to "Copy File Path" but since they don't I'm looking for another way to do this.

They have an option for revealing the file in finder. If I do that then I can get the path with Quicksilver, but I don't want the extra step.

I'm looking for a free Copy Path to Clipboard program so that I can select a file, choose Open With, select said program, and then have the path copied to my clipboard.

I don't really want to do this with Applescript because sometimes it is a bit slow to load / run. Also, I'm not sure if it would show up in the "Recommended Types" of programs for any given file.

I would be OK with running a shell script to do this, I have worked on one for other purposes,

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1 | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy
```

But I have not really been able to turn this into an application and have it work in the way I've mentioned.

**Get File Path**

This Program did what I wanted, but it is large for what it does (~5mb!?), and it is not free, and it also shows up for a second while copying the path, which is kind of annoying.

**Get Path**

Get Path by Minder Softworks does work, but it is applescript based, and it prompts you for which type of path you want each time you try and copy a path, which is also annoying. For the record I want the unix style path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to start with that shell script and use [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus) to wrap it in an app bundle.

Comment: That worked well for me. I had to use the dropable option though, for anyone else trying to recreate this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use that shell script in Automator and add a stage before it to 'Get Selected Finder Items'. Save this as an application somewhere and then just drag it to your finder sidebar. Then you can drag files or folders onto it and it automatically copies the path.

Answer (score 0):

[FileUtilsCM](http://free.abracode.com/cmworkshop/file_utils.html) is free and has many other file related tools.
It is a contextual menu item.